# How to know if previous insert to textbox was equal to actual insert

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, equality, temporary

Can you help me figure out, how to know if previous text inserted to the textbox, and actual insert is equal to each other?

For example if I insert "word 1" to text box, then enter it, and after I insert "word 2" in this case nothing happens, but if I insert "word 1" again after "word 1", I must know about it.

Comparison of recorded and inputed lines does not make sense in this case, because I do not always save string into the text file, but I want to know if string is same with actual insert and previous insert comparison, even if line does not exist in file.

I need value which exist between two actual and previous inserts and if previous insert is equal to actual insert, display this fact, annul value, but if actual insert  is different  remove this temporal value.

I'm not sure how to properly get this result for actual insert with textbox, how to know about equality for next and previous insert.

I'm sure my attempt is bad and probably wrong, and my question would be rated as bad, but anyway:

I'm trying to add actual string record to the list with 0 index, then if next actual value is equal to string in this list, make field variable value equal to 1 and clear list, otherwise clear list and annul field variable value. Then if field variable is not equal to zero display "Repeat of previous insert" and annul field variable value, clear temporal list.

But seems like comparison of `actStr` and list record `rpt[0]` it is not comparison of previous and actual, but just actual with actual, so it does not works proper, ans looks like absolutely wrong way to do it:

```
 List<string> rpt = new List<string>();      

 string tempRptCheck = actStr;
 rpt.Insert(0, tempRptCheck);

 if (actStr == rpt[0])
 {
    rptVal = (rptVal = 1);
    rpt.Clear();
 }
 else
 {
    rptVal = (rptVal = 0);
    rpt.Clear();
 }

 if (rptVal > 0) 
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Repeat of previous insert");
    rptVal = (rptVal = 0);    
    rpt.Clear();
 }
```

To be clearer again:

I want get notification in case if actual input is equal to previous input, for example:

Insert to textbox is a string "word1", then press enter to further process. So it must be recorded in the list, and if following insert is equal to this previous insert, with same "word1", notify me about this equality, remove this string form the list and change it to actual "word1",  and if next insert will be same again, do the same.

But if insert is "word1",  it must be recorded to this list, and if following insert is not equal to this previous insert,   remove this string form the list and change it to actual "word2" to avoid such case  if  insert is "word1", and following insert is "word2" not equal to this previous, and then next following insert is "word1" again equal to before last, it should not be considered as repetition.

So I want get notification of repetition only between  actual and prevous, or to put it differently actual and next inserts.

To be more clear, I want exactly this logic, which works with desired result only with console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var words = new List<string>();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Add word: ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (words.Contains(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{input} is already in the list!");
                continue;  
            }
            words.Clear();
            words.Add(input);
        }        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

but It does not works with textbox, I got same result as with code above: each request as already exist. `And while (true)` loops in endless cycle, because same happens here, actual equals actual.

Also I've tried this way, to pass value about repeated text to field variable `rpt` but it does not works:

```
string OldText = string.Empty;
private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OldText = textBox1.Text;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string newText = textBox1.Text;

   if (newText == OldText)
   {
      rpt = (rpt = 1);
   }
   else
   {
      rpt = (rpt = 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: not sure for UI what you are using? winforms? ASP.net? What you can do is create a static variable and on textbox_changed event(in case on winforms) or onblur(if you are using js) compare the current textbox value with the static variable.
Hope that helps!

Comment: @Dirty Developer  hello, winforms. I've tried with textbox_changed event it is show now, I edited my question, but still can't figure out

Comment: What are the "double assignments (`rpt = (rpt = 1)`) good for? When in doubt, compare `string`s (objects in general) using `.Equals` (`object.Equals(x, y)`, if neither is _known_ not to be 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it with simple code. use _Leave event of textbox. Also, make sure to clear the list before entering new values.
Also, I have declared the List variable at class level:

```
 List<string> a = new List<string>();

private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(a.Contains(textBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Notify");
        }
        else
        {
            a.Clear();
            a.Add(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: looks like, it must work, but not, I also checked  it if   value updated with label next to the `MessageBox.Show("Notify");`, but not,  no changes. Can't get what is wrong here.

Comment: Not sure, what is the issue with your winform. I have created a new winform and created a test application and it is working fine for me :) can you please provide the full design as well as code ?

Comment: with raw insert or with regex corrections for inserted text with textBox1_TextChanged event I got same result. Not sure, which part of I have to provide, it is large, part which is in relation does nothing nothing, just insert textBox1_KeyDown and then (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter). textBox1_TextChanged is empty but if I use regex there, no mater, same result, nothing

Comment: @TimR, can you create a small application and paste the above code.
I am sure it will run. this way you can find there is something causing problems with your winforms.  also use _Leave event, not textChanged

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `List`, because you want compare only against last inserted value. Instance of string is enough.

For example if your form have three TextBoxes. You can use `Leave` eventhandler, because you want check against last inserted text only when user finish with current TextBox and moving to the another. `TextChanged` will be raised every time you add or remove character

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private string _LastInsertedText;

    public MyForm()
    {
        thisTextBox1.Leave += TextBox_Leave;
        thisTextBox2.Leave += TextBox_Leave;
        thisTextBox3.Leave += TextBox_Leave;
    }

    private void TextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        if(textbox.Text.Equals(_LastInsertedText))
        {
            // notify about same value
        }
        else
        {
            _LastInsertedText = textbox.Text
        }
    }
}
```

It will notify only when you move focus to another control

If you want notify about equality only if inserted value is same as previously inserted in this TextBox, then use `TextBox.Tag` property

```
private void TextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    var previousText = (string)textbox.Tag;
    if(textbox.Text.Equals(previousText))
    {
        // notify about same value
    }
    else
    {
        textbox.Tag = textbox.Text
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure what is wrong here, I have no any updates or regex on textbox_change event, but if I use this code TextBox_Leave with textbox.Tag, I got  same result, as with solution by  Dirty Developer . Just does not notifies me about same value, no changes. There is nothing special, between previous and actual insert, user writes text, then press enter, I even removed the cleaning of the textbox field after press enter, if it may be cause, but not, it does not works

Comment: @TimR, are you sure `Enter`(break line) isn't added to the input value? can you show your code you have.

Comment: Yes sure, I checked it with regex and without for such possibilities , but result is same, no mater if it is absolutely raw  insert or with different corrections for inserted text with `textBox1_TextChanged` event. Not sure, which part of code to show, it is large, but code which is in relation with textbox, there is nothing special,  insert `textBox1_KeyDown` and then `(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)`.  textBox1_TextChanged is empty but no mater if I use regex corrections, in both cases I have no desired result

Comment: You always can debug your code line by line and check why it do not go in `MessageBox.Show("Notify")` line

Comment: can't catch it, nothing is there